Spark stuck, cannot read kafka
I installed kafka and spark on docker, and use pyspark on local to code. but when I run, it's stuck and raise error timeout. i dont know why or what error
enter image description here
this is my docker-compose file
enter image description here
hope someone can help me fix it

Can you add your code as text, not image?

It's not stuck. It is failing to connect and timing out... localhost:9092 is not where Kafka is running. It should be kafka:29092, based on your compose file

@OneCricketeer i did try that, but still not working
